# Matlab read txt, sum values until condition,

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file that contains two columns: the first holds the date, the second holds a floating point value of precipitation (ppt) on that date. I would like to read through the precipitation column and sum the precipitation for each storm. Storms are separated by periods of zero precipiation. Therefore, I basically want to tell Matlab to read through the ppt column, sum the values until it reads a 0, put the sum into a cell of a vector, and then keep reading and repeating. I know I need a loop with a conditional statement. Here is what I think a successful code might resemble based on my limited knowledge of Matlab:

```
fid = fopen(12hr_ppt.txt');
C = textscan(fid);
l = length(fid);
? = 0;
for i=1:l;
    if fid(i)>0;
        ?=fid(i)+?;
    else
        ?=0;
    endif
    fprintf(?);
end
```

So I basically want ? to be a vector that holds the summed precipitation amounts. It would also be really nice to have the dates that correspond to the events as well but for now I just want to tackle this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well in MATLAB,you don't have to worry about declaring a specific data tyep,it allows you to declare on the go,for example where you've put the question mark,you could write V=0,and later in the loop V(i)=fid(i)+V(i)...

Comment: and from what I've understood you want to keep summing values until you encounter a zero,for that it's better to initialize another variable as an index of vector "V" and increment it only when you're done with one sum...

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along these lines:

```
clear;
close;
clc;

date_ppt = importdata('testcase.txt');
num_rows = size(date_ppt.data,1);
end_storm = find(date_ppt.data == 0);
if(end_storm(1) == 1)
    end_storm = end_storm(2:end);
end
if(end_storm(end) ~= num_rows)
    end_storm = [end_storm;num_rows];
end
begin_storm = [1;(end_storm(1:(end-1)) + 1)];

accumulated_ppt = zeros(size(begin_storm));

for i = 1:numel(accumulated_ppt)
    accumulated_ppt(i) = sum(date_ppt.data(begin_storm(i):end_storm(i)));
end

accumulated_ppt
```

Here, my "testcase.txt" contains the following:

```
Date    PPT
01/01/13    0.276
02/01/13    0.6797
03/01/13    0.6551
04/01/13    0.1626
05/01/13    0
06/01/13    0.4984
07/01/13    0.9597
08/01/13    0.3404
09/01/13    0.5853
10/01/13    0.2238
11/01/13    0.7513
12/01/13    0.2551
13/01/13    0.506
14/01/13    0.6991
15/01/13    0.8909
16/01/13    0.9593
17/01/13    0.5472
18/01/13    0
19/01/13    0.1493
20/01/13    0.2575
21/01/13    0.8407
22/01/13    0.2543
23/01/13    0.8143
24/01/13    0.2435
25/01/13    0.9293
26/01/13    0.35
27/01/13    0.1966
28/01/13    0.2511
29/01/13    0.616
30/01/13    0.4733
31/01/13    0.3517
01/02/13    0.8308
02/02/13    0.5853
03/02/13    0.5497
04/02/13    0.9172
05/02/13    0.2858
06/02/13    0.7572
07/02/13    0.7537
08/02/13    0.3804
09/02/13    0.5678
10/02/13    0.0759
11/02/13    0
12/02/13    0.5308
13/02/13    0.7792
14/02/13    0.934
15/02/13    0.1299
16/02/13    0.5688
17/02/13    0.4694
18/02/13    0.0119
19/02/13    0.3371
```

The output obtained was:

```
accumulated_ppt =

    1.7734
    7.2165
   11.4314
    3.7611
```

In addition, the "Date" column values are stored in `date_ppt.textdata(:,1)`. If you want, say, just the dates corresponding to `end_storm`, you can simply use `date_ppt.textdata(end_storm,1)':

```
>> date_ppt.textdata(end_storm,1)

ans = 

    '04/01/13'
    '17/01/13'
    '10/02/13'
    '18/02/13'
```

Comment: Thank you very much Roney! I tried your code and received an error on the line 'accumulated_ppt(i) = sum(date_ppt.data(begin_storm(i):end_storm(i)));' I get "unexpected MATLAB expression.

Comment: @mr.cooper: Oh? I'd tried the code myself.. saved it as a script in the same folder as "testcase.txt" and ran it.. Worked fine for me.